# Есть ли какие-либо библиотеки на Python, чтобы распозновать математические графики

Tags: python, математика, графики

Допустим у меня есть картинка с графиком[image: картинка графика]

мне нужно определить параметры этого графика.

Для более подробного изложения вопроса я добавлю еще один пример[image: картинка 2]

На рисунке изображён график функции вида f(x)= a/(x+b) +c

нужно определить параметры a,b,c по картинке

Можете оставить ссылку на статью или библиотеку(Python).

Comment: А это какая-то реальная задача или просто из интереса? Мне просто интересно, где это может быть применимо вообще, зачем это может быть нужно

Comment: вообще больше для себя, но это может помочь тем, кто пишет ЕГЭ(9 задание) или олимпиадникам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже была такая мысль и тоже связанная с ЕГЭ пару лет назад, тогда руки до написания своего решения так и не дошли, сейчас предлагаю вот эту [библиотеку](https://github.com/dilawar/PlotDigitizer)

Я проверил с первым графиком - он полностью считан [image: введите сюда описание изображения]